# Организация таска компиляции sass в Gulp

Tags: gulp, компиляция, sass, gulp-sass

Какие следует использовать плагины `Gulp` для более грамотной, с точки зрения эргономики ресурсов, уменьшения времени выполнения компиляции для организации таска.

*Структура проекта следующая:*

```
   dev  
     |--component1  // компоненты проекта
     |--component2  
     .....
     |--scss  
       |--base  // базовые подключаемые файлы с миксинами и прочим
       |--elements  // общие для всех страниц элементы оформления (кнопки и т.д.)
       |--componets    
         |--component1     
           |--style.scss     
         |--component2     
          ........    
       |--main.scss
```

Собирается все это так:

```
app  
   |--component1  // компоненты 
     |--css       // отдельные стили каждого компонента
       |--style.css   
   |--component2   
    .....     
   |--css  // главный css
     |--style.css
```

Таск sass для всего этого добра:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return combiner(
        gulp.src([
                    'dev/scss/main.scss' ,
                    'dev/scss/project components/**/*.scss'
        ]),
        debug({title: 'src'}),
        gulpIf(isDevelop, sourcemaps.init()),
        sass( sassOptions ),
        autoprefixer({
                browsers: ['last 4 versions']
            }),
        gulpIf(isDevelop, sourcemaps.write()),
        rename(function (path) {
            path.dirname += '/css';
            path.basename = 'main' ? 'style' : path.basename;
        }),
        gulpIf(!isDevelop, cleanCSS()),
        gulp.dest('app'),
        debug({title: 'dest'})
    ).on('error', notify.onError(function(err){
            return {
                title: 'sass',
                message: err.message
            }
    }))

});
```

Сейчас при выполнении задачи в папку app помещаются все файлы из папок компонентов и главный файл стилей, независимо от того модифицировались они или нет. Хотелось бы что-бы манипуляции производились только с модифицируемыми файлами + непонятен вопрос с кешированием подключаемых через `@import` файлов.

Так же вопрос добавления удаления файлов и переписывания урлов к файлам подключаемым через css (картинки, шрифты...)

Буду признателен за подробные ответы и советы по организации таска.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В идеале сборка должна быть такая, чтобы скомпилированный файлы, которые будут отдаваться пользователю, лежали отдельно от исходников и их можно было спокойно удалить при необходимости. К тому же, это позволит делать дополнительные оптимизации с исходными файлами и не менять пути в сборке.

#### Организация стилей

В целом, вы отлично организовали сборку стилей: организовали переменные окружения, добавили афтопрефиксер. Однако я бы посоветовал создать два отдельных таска для разного окружения, чтобы исключить дополнительные условия. К тому же, можно было бы в качестве путей добавить лишь `'dev/scss/main.scss'` и в нем же делать `@import`'ы к остальным файлам.

Также бы посоветовал добавить `livereload()`, чтобы при изменении файлов ваш локальный сервер автоматически подгружал все изменения.

Также не пойму, как вы бы хотели, чтобы манипуляции производились только с модифицируемыми файлами. Если вы компилируете все scss-файлы в один `main.css`, то операции будут производиться над всем `main.css`, уже после сборки. Если вы хотите, чтобы манипуляции производились лишь с тем файлом, который вы меняете, нужно каждый из этих файлов подключать к документу и не объединять при разработке.

#### Организация картинок

Я бы посоветовал хранить исходные картинки отдельно и переносить их при компиляции в папку сборки (назовем ее `public`). Кроме обычного переноса было бы хорошо эти картинки сжать:

К примеру, картинки можно легко сжать без потери качества только за счет удаление exif-данных. На реальном сайте можно сократить размер картинок в среднем на 70%, что на современном сайте равняется примерно 4 МБ. Пример на `gulp`:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    imageminJR = require('imagemin-jpeg-recompress'),
    imageminSvgo = require('imagemin-svgo');

// Optimizing images
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
    gulp.src('./img/**/*')
        .pipe(imagemin([
            imageminJR({
                method: 'ms-ssim'
            }),
            imageminSvgo({
                plugins: [
                    {removeViewBox: false}
                ]
            })
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/img/'))
});
```

А для браузеров, которые понимают легковесный формат `webp` (формат разработан Google), можно сделать еще такой вариант изображений:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    webp = require('gulp-webp');

// Generate Webp
gulp.task('webp', function() {
    gulp.src('./img/**/*')
        .pipe(webp())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/img/'))
});
```

#### Организация шрифтов

Тоже самое касается шрифтов, однако их нужно лишь перемещать в `public`:

```
// Replace fonts
gulp.task('fonts', function () {
    gulp.src('./fonts/text-font/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/fonts/'))
});
```

#### Создание иконочного шрифта

Предпочтительней было бы использование иконичного шрифта вместо картинок-спрайтов. И у этого метода есть ряд преимуществ:

1. Более меньший вес шрифта, чем спрайта;
2. Гибкость стилизации через CSS;
3. Меньший вес CSS;
4. Гибкий размер и ненадобность создание версий для Retina-дисплеев.

Для генерации иконочного шрифта я бы посоветовал такую комбинацию:

```
// Generate icon font
gulp.task('iconfont', function() {
    var
        fontName = 'icon-font',
        cssClass = 'i';
    // Исходные SVG-файлы
    gulp.src(['./fonts/icon-font/*.svg'])
        .pipe(iconfontCss({
            fontName: fontName,
            cssClass: cssClass,
            path: './styl/mixins/icon-font.styl',
            targetPath: '../../styl/components/font/icon-font.styl',
            fontPath: '../fonts/'
        }))
        .pipe(iconfont({
            fontName: fontName,
            prependUnicode: true,
            normalize: true,
            formats: ['svg','ttf','woff','woff2']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/fonts/'));
});
```

Миски для стилей, который берется из этой строки `path: './styl/mixins/icon-font.styl'` будет выглядеть так:

```
@font-face
    font-family "<%= fontName %>"
    src: url('<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.woff') format('woff'),
         url('<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.svg#<%= fontName %>') format('svg')

[class*="i-"]
    position relative
    display inline-block
    width 1em
    height 1em
    &:before
        font 14px '<%= fontName %>'
        font-size inherit
        text-rendering auto
        speak none
        font-variant normal
        text-transform none
        color inherit
        position absolute
        top 50%
        left 50%
        transform translate(-50%, -50%)

<% _.each(glyphs, function(glyph) { %>
.<%= cssClass %>-<%= glyph.fileName %>:before
  content "\<%= glyph.codePoint %>"
<% }); %>
```

После генерации шрифта все, что вам нужно будет сделать, это подключить сгенированный CSS к вашему сайту или инглудить его к главному CSS-файлу, а затем использовать таким образом:

```
<span class="i-<<имя исходного SVG-файла>>"></span>
```

Comment: _Также не пойму, как вы бы хотели, чтобы манипуляции производились только с модифицируемыми файлами._  Папка, где ведется разработка организована следующим образом: есть папки `project components` в ней папки с различными **отдельными** , **не зависящими**  друг от друга компонентами проекта, у каждого должен быть  свой файл стилей и индексный документ.

Comment: Так же есть папка `scss` в корне которого лежит `main.scss` - это общий файл стилей для всех компонентов, так же в ней есть папки с файлами миксинов и прочими подключаемыми файлами и папка  где лежат те самые файлы стилей для компонентов проекта `style.scss`, разложенные по папкам с названием компонента. В каждый из них так же идут импорты подключаемых файлов (миксины, экстенды, сетка...)

Comment: Так вот, хотелось бы мне, когда работаешь над  стилем одного компонента в папку сборки попадал только он один, а не вся куча целеком,  (имеется ввиду отдельные `style.css` на выходе каждого компонента). + интересен вопрос с кешированием подключаемых файлов. при пересборке, допустим я изменил только `main.scss` а в него подключен `extend.scss` последний будет обработан заново или его содержимое возьмется из кеша? Как сделать что бы бралось из кеша?

Comment: + вопрос добавления, удаления файла....

Answer (score 3):

Для ускорения процесса компиляции в целом, можно начать пользоваться модулем **[gulp-load-plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-load-plugins)**. При помощи него вам не придется подключать все плагины, даже если они вам не нужны в данный момент, достаточно подключать их во время выполнения определенного таска. Т. е. в обычном виде вы запускаете таск *styles*, а подключаются все плагины — от минификации картинок до бабель-транспайлера. Этот плагин автоматически собирает содержимое *packages.json* и обрезает часть **gulp-** для использования. В результате, например, использование *gulp-uglify* будет выглядеть так:

```
const $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')()
...
.pipe($.uglify({preserveComments: 'some'}))
```

Вместо:

```
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
...
.pipe(uglify({preserveComments: 'some'}))
```

---

Для ускорения процесса компиляции в частности, а именно таска по обработке стилей, можно воспользоваться **[gulp-newer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer)**.

Вот примерный код, которым можно воспользоваться. Обратите внимание на строчку `.pipe($.newer('.tmp/styles'))` и промежуточное сохранение в папку *tmp* после работы плагина SASS. Знак `$` — это горячее подключение плагинов при помощи *gulp-load-plugins*.

```js
gulp.task('styles', () => {
  return gulp.src([
    'app/styles/**/*.scss',
    'app/styles/**/*.css'
  ])
    .pipe($.newer('.tmp/styles'))
    .pipe($.sass({
      precision: 10,
      includePaths: require('node-bourbon').includePaths
    }).on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.rename({
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
    .pipe(gcmq())
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.cssnano({
      discardUnused: false
    })))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: "last 4 versions"
    }))
    .pipe($.size({title: 'styles'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream({match: '**/*.css'}));
});
```

---

«непонятен вопрос с кешированием подключаемых через `@import` файлов» — уточните, что именно вы имеете в виду. Пока что мне кажется, что эта часть никак не связана с галп-тасками.

«Так же вопрос добавления удаления файлов и переписывания урлов к файлам подключаемым через css (картинки, шрифты...)» — аналогично, поясните что имеется в виду.

Comment: Да не могу разобраться  никак стоит ли использовать `gulp-cahed` и `gulp-remember`... т.е. без них как работает `libsass`. допустим к файлу подключены несколько импортов, при компиляции эти импорты будут обрабатываться заново  или они как то кешируются, при условии,что меняется только `main.scss`

Comment: В sass так или иначе все будет завязано на импортах, если вы хотите модульность. Чтобы при компиляции обрабатывались только те файлы, которые изменились, как раз и используется `gulp-newer`.

Comment: `newer` я использую перед  `dest` что-бы записывать только изменившиеся файлы, так как помимо `main.scss` есть еще отдельные файлы стилей, которые так же обрабатываются но если они не менялись зачем их писать....